# Error in mysql while importing

Tags: mysql

I have tried to import a MySQL file that was exported and given by client in sql format. When I tried to import I got the following error:

```
   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
  `black_or_african_american` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
  ' at line 33
```

my query is:

```
       CREATE TABLE `ZipCodeTable` (
                  `zip` int(5) NOT NULL,
                  `type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
                  `primary_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
                  `acceptable_cities` varchar(2555) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                  `unacceptable_cities` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                  `state` char(2) NOT NULL,
                  `county` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `timezone` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `area_codes` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `latitude` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT 0,
                  `longitude` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT 0,
                  `precise_latitude` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT 0,
                  `precise_longitude` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT 0,
                  `latitude_min` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT 0,
                  `latitude_max` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT 0,
                  `longitude_min` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT 0,
                  `longitude_max` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT 0,
                  `world_region` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `country` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
                  `decommissioned` int DEFAULT 0,
                  `estimated_population` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `area_land` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `population_count_100` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `housing_unit_count_100` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `white` varchar(5) decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `black_or_african_american` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `american_indian_or_alaskan_native` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `asian`decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `native_hawaiian_and_other_pacific_islander` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `other_race` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `two_or_more_races`decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `total_male_population` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `total_female_population` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_under_10` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_10_to_19` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_20_to_29` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_30_to_39` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_40_to_49` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_50_to_59` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_60_to_69` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_70_to_79` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                  `pop_80_plus` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I dont know to identify the error..
Can anyone help me??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line

```
`white` varchar(5) decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,
```

you try to define two types for one column. Just remove one and you'll be fine.

Comment: I have removed that.. now i am getting this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 45

Answer (score 2):

here in this line

```
`white` varchar(5) decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0
```

write either varchar(5) or Decimal(7,0)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 column definition for `column white`:
`white varchar(5) decimal(7,0) DEFAULT 0,`